# 8. Suppose that two balanced dice are rolled. Define the three events A, B and C as follows:

Tags: probability

A= the first die shows an even number.
B= the sum in the two dice is 4.
C= the two outcomes in the two dice differ at most by 2. That is, C = {(x, y) : |x − y| ≤ 2}.
(a) Show that P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(A)P(B)P(A).
(b) Show that P(A ∩ B) does not equal P(A)P(B)

I think P(A) is 1/2
P(B) is 1/12 and P(C) is 1/2. Unsure how to find (a) and (b)

Comment: What is the "8."?

Comment: You need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)$ and  $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate P(A ∩ B ∩ C)

Comment: For P(A ∩ B) I have 1/36 since the only shared subset of A and B is (2,2). Then I have P(A) * P(B) = 1/2 *1/12 = 1/24 which shows they are not equal

Comment: Did you mean $\Pr(A \cap B \cap C) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$?

Comment: $P(C) = 2/3.$ not $1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

You have found that $A\cap B$ is the event where: the first die shows an even number, and the sum of the two dice is $4$. So $A\cap B=\{(2,2)\}$, and hence $\mathsf P(A\cap B)= 1/36\neq (1/2)(1/12)= \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)$.

$A\cap B\cap C$ is the event where: the first die shows an even number, the sum of the two dice is $4$, and the two outcomes in the two dice differ at most by $2$.

> $$A\cap B\cap C=\{(2,2)\}$$

---

PS:
$$\mathsf P(C)~{= {\small\mathsf P(\{{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)},{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)},{(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5)},{(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6)}, {(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6)}, {(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)}\})}\\=24/36}$$